# How to tune the number of epochs of a neural network in a cross-validation setup?

Tags: neural-networks, cross-validation

In orden to avoid overfitting, how I can choose the correct amount of epochs?

I should be create 3 splits (train, valid and test) for each fold??

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this to avoid overfitting, than standard, and less computationally demanding, approach would be to use [early stopping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Early_stopping), i.e. periodically check test error and stop training when it does not decrease anymore. All the major deep learning libraries have functionalities for enabling early stopping during training, but it is trivial to implement it from the scratch as well.

Comment: I undestand, but can I use early stop in a cross-validation setup? In that case, it is common have 3 split in cross-validation (train/validation/test)?

Comment: @Xtalker you *need* separate test/validation set for early stopping, since you need to evaluate the test/validation set performance to use it.